# How can i resolve seat color?

Tags: flutter

Hello I am stuck in my seat screen where I have loaded data from json which is in asset
if seat is reserved then its color change to blue if not then white
whenever user tap to choose seat then particular seat color change to amber.
But  I m getting problem whenever tap for one seat then all free seat color change to amber.

```
 class _ArrangeSeat extends StatefulWidget {
  const _ArrangeSeat({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_ArrangeSeat> createState() => __ArrangeSeatState();
}

class __ArrangeSeatState extends State<_ArrangeSeat> {
  late Future<List<SeatSelection>> getSeat;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSeat = showData();
  }

  Future<List<SeatSelection>> showData() async {
    try {
      final data = await rootBundle.loadString('asset/seat.json');
      final jsonResult = json.decode(data) as List<dynamic>;
      //seatSelection!.add(jsonResult);

      return jsonResult.map((e) => SeatSelection.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } catch (error) {
      return Future.error(error);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var dataStore = Provider.of<SeatSelectionScreenProvider>(context);

    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      future: showData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          var data = snapshot.data as List<SeatSelection>;
          dataStore.seatSelection = [];
          dataStore.setData(data);
          //  print("Snapshot:${data.toString()}");

          List<SeatSelection> item =
              Provider.of<SeatSelectionScreenProvider>(context).seatSelection!;
          return SizedBox(
            height: screenSize.height / 2,
            child: Consumer<SeatSelectionScreenProvider>(
                builder: (context, value, child) {
              if (value.seatSelection != null) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 9,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    ),
                    itemCount: item.length - 1,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Provider.of<SeatSelectionScreenProvider>(context)
                          .getIndex(index);
                      return item[index].isSpace!
                          ? Container()
                          : Seats(
                              seat: item,
                              index: index,
                            );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }),
          );
        }
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class Seats extends StatefulWidget {
  Seats({Key? key, this.index, this.seat}) : super(key: key);

  List<SeatSelection>? seat;
  int? index;

  @override
  State<Seats> createState() => _SeatsState();
}

class _SeatsState extends State<Seats> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = Provider.of<SeatSelectionScreenProvider>(context);
    // print("  Seat data :${widget.seat}");
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        // Provider.of<SeatSelectionScreenProvider>(context, listen: false)
        //     .getCurrentSeat(widget.index!);
        print("ClickedIndex:${widget.index}");
        print("Seat:${widget.seat![widget.index!].seat}");
        provider.checkSelectSeat(widget.index!, widget.seat!); 
      },
      child: Container(
        width: screenSize.width * 0.04,
        height: screenSize.height * 0.02,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: provider.seatColor(widget.index!, widget.seat!),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            border: Border.all(
                color: provider.seatColor(widget.index!, widget.seat!))),
        child:
            Center(child: Text(widget.seat![widget.index!].seat!.toString())),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And i have code logic in provider here it is

```
class SeatSelectionScreenProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool? isSelected = false;
  List<int> totalSeat = [];
  List<SeatSelection>? seatSelection = [];
  int? index;
  int? currentSeatIndex;

  getCurrentSeat(int index) {
    print("Index:${index}");
    if (index != null) {
      currentSeatIndex = index;
      print("CurrentSeat:${currentSeatIndex!}");
    }
  }

  void checkSelectSeat(int currentIndex, List<SeatSelection> seat) {
    print(index!);
    print("Provider seat Index :${seat[currentIndex].seat}");
    //print(" Provider seat :${seatSelection}");
    print(" Current seat No:");
    print(seatSelection![index!].seat);
    print(
        "Check seat:${seatSelection![index!].seat == seat[currentIndex].seat}");
    if (seatSelection![index!].seat == seat[index!].seat &&
        seatSelection![currentSeatIndex!].isFree == true) {
      isSelected = !isSelected!;
      print("Seat Status:$isSelected");
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  getIndex(int currentSeatNo) 
    //  print("Get currentSeat:$currentSeatNo");
    if (currentSeatNo != null) {
      index = currentSeatNo;
      //  print("Get index:$index");
    }
  }

  setData(List<SeatSelection>? getSeat) {
    if (getSeat != null) {
      seatSelection!.addAll(getSeat);
    }
  }

  Color seatColor(int currentIndex, List<SeatSelection> seat) {
    if (seat[index!].isReserved!) {
      print(index);
      // print("Reserved seat:${seatSelection![index!].seat!}");
      // print("check Free seat:${seatSelection![index!].seat == index}");
      return Colors.blue;
    } else if (seat[index!].isAvailable!) {
      //  print("Available  seat:${seatSelection![index!].seat!}");
      return Colors.red;
    } else if (seat[index!].isFree == true &&
        seat[currentIndex].seat == seatSelection![index!].seat &&
        isSelected == true) {
      print("check Free seat:${seatSelection![index!].seat == index}");
      print("User select seat:${seatSelection![currentIndex].seat}");
      notifyListeners();
      return Colors.amber;
    } else {
      return Colors.black12;
    }
  }
```

JSON file

```
  {
    "seat": 8,
    "price": 400,
    "is_reserved": true,
    "is_space": false,
    "is_available": false,
    "is_free":false
},
{
    "seat": 9,
    "price": 400,
    "is_reserved": false,
    "is_space": false,
    "is_available": false,
    "is_free":true
},
{
    "price": 400,
    "is_reserved": true,
    "is_space": true,
    "is_available": false,
    "is_free":false
},
{
    "price": 400,
    "is_reserved": true,
    "is_space": true,
    "is_available": false
},
```

SeatSelection Model here

```
import 'dart:convert';

       List<SeatSelection> seatSelectionFromJson(String str) => 
   List<SeatSelection>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => 
      SeatSelection.fromJson(x)));
                   
  String seatSelectionToJson(List<SeatSelection> data) => 
   json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

 class SeatSelection {
SeatSelection({
    this.seat,
    this.price,
    this.isReserved,
    this.isSpace,
    this.isAvailable,
    this.isFree,
});

int ?seat;
int ?price;
bool ?isReserved;
bool ?isSpace;
bool ?isAvailable;
bool ?isFree;

factory SeatSelection.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SeatSelection(
    // ignore: prefer_if_null_operators
    seat: json["seat"] == null ? null : json["seat"],
    price: json["price"],
    isReserved: json["is_reserved"],
    isSpace: json["is_space"],
    isAvailable: json["is_available"],
    // ignore: prefer_if_null_operators
    isFree: json["is_free"] == null ? null : json["is_free"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    // ignore: prefer_if_null_operators
    "seat": seat == null ? null : seat,
    "price": price,
    "is_reserved": isReserved,
    "is_space": isSpace,
    "is_available": isAvailable,
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    "is_free": isFree == null ? null : isFree,
};
```

}

Comment: can you add your json response here to understand better to solve?

Comment: also the class SeatSelection

Answer (score 0):

[image: listtile example image]Code to change ListTile color to blue when user taps on it

```
class ListTileEg extends StatefulWidget {
ListTileEg({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<ListTileEg> createState() => _ListTileEgState();
}

class _ListTileEgState extends State<ListTileEg> {
final List<int> _list = List.generate(10, (i) => i);

final List<bool> _isSelected = List.generate(10, (i) => false);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('${_list[index].toString()}'),
          tileColor:
              _isSelected[index] == true ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
          onTap: () => setState(() {
            _isSelected[index] = !_isSelected[index];
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i make list of bool

Comment: what i suggest you is to add isSelected param and set default value false to SeatSelection and then you can change color of tile when isSelected is true and update your data